# UIAlertView multi line alert inserting linebreak

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am creating a multi line UIAlertView, however for some reason the width of the UIAlertView is too small for one of my NSString so it puts a line break in and upts the error onto two lines...

this is what my code looks like

e

```
lse if ((checkCustomerName == NO)||(checkCustomerEmail == NO)||(checkCustomerRating == NO)||(checkBranchID == NO)||(checkServerAddress == NO)||(checkPortNumber == NO)||(nameTextField == NO)||(emailTextField == NO)) {

        NSMutableString *alertString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];


        if (checkCustomerName == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid name \n"];
        }
        if (checkCustomerEmail == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid e-mail \n"];
        }
        if (checkCustomerRating == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"Select a slimey to define your experiance \n"];
        }
        if (checkBranchID == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid BranchID \n"];
        }
        if (checkServerAddress == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid Server address \n"];
        }
        if (checkPortNumber == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid port address \n"];
        }
        if (nameTextField == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid name, too many characters \n"];
        }
        if (emailTextField == NO) {
            [alertString appendString: @"invalid e-mail, too many characters \n"];
        }



        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Errors" message:alertString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

        [alert show];


    }
```

This is how the text appears

Errors

invalid name
invalid e-mail
Select a smiley to define your
experiance // this is where its going wrong... it should be on the same line

So what I would like to know is how to make that text appear on the same line, for instance how to make the uialerview wider

Comment: You're better of making your own alert from scratch if you want to change things like this. UIAlertView wasn't really designed to be messed with too much.

Comment: well thats unfortunate... okay thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to solve this problem by changing the scope of the problem itself and looking at what the result will be. If someone manages to screw up all 8 fields, you're going to have an alert box with all 8 strings concatenated. Seems like a really nasty UI to have all those strings in 1 box. Why not refactor your code so that if a user manages to screw up just one of those tests, it will alert them with the first failure reason, then return. 1 message for 1 problem at a time. Also takes care of your concatenation problem with the newlines.

I'm not sure why the line breaks aren't working in this situation but you might consider trying to use `stringByAppendingString:` or maybe `stringWithFormat:`.

Or it could be something UIAlertView is doing behind the scenes...